# Facing authentication issues while deploying Rails App on AWS EC2 using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-ec2, deployment, capistrano

I first deployed using git clone in /var/www/AppName directory and was able to successfully deploy it. I then tried using capistrano and link it with my git. I am following this [Link](https://medium.com/@KerrySheldon/ec2-exercise-1-6-deploy-a-rails-app-to-an-ec2-instance-using-capistrano-3485238e4a4a) to deploy app using capistrano. I am facing authentication issues.

My deploy.rb file is

```
set :application, 'blog'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:abc@def.com/blog.git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.6.5'
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/blog'
set :use_sudo, true
```

and production.rb is

```
role :app, %w[deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com]
role :web, %w[deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com]
role :db,  %w[deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com]
set :ssh_options, {
  keys: %w[/d/Manna/Learning/RoR/EC2-Ubuntu.pem],
  forward_agent: true,
  user: 'deploy_user',
  auth_methods: %w[publickey password]
}
```

However, I am facing issues in authentication of deploy_user on EC2. I am able to SSH into EC2 using pem key. Here is the output when i try using "cap production deploy --trace"

> ** Invoke production (first_time)
>   ** Execute production
>   ** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
>   ** Execute load:defaults
>   ** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
>   ** Invoke passenger:rvm:hook (first_time)
>   ** Invoke passenger:test_which_passenger (first_time)
>   ** Execute passenger:test_which_passenger deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com's
>   password:
>
> run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>           12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in
>   `block (2 levels) in execute'
>           11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in`
>   run'
>           10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in
>   `instance_exec'
>            9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-passenger-0.2.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/passenger.cap:42:in`
>   block (3 levels) in '
>            8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:61:in
>   `test'
>            7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in`
>   create_command_and_execute'
>            6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in
>   `tap'
>            5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in`
>   block in create_command_and_execute'
>            4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:130:in
>   `execute_command'
>            3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:177:in`
>   with_ssh'
>            2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in
>   `with'
>            1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in`
>   call'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.0.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:268:in
>   `start': Authentication failed for user
>   deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>   (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)
>           1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in`
>   block (2 levels) in execute'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in
>   `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as
>   deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:
>   Authentication failed for user
>   deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>   (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError) cap aborted!
>   SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as
>   deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:
>   Authentication failed for user
>   deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in`
>   rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in
>   `block (2 levels) in execute' Caused by:
>   Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user
>   deploy_user@ec2-13-232-140-179.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.0.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:268:in`
>   start'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in
>   `call'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in`
>   with'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:177:in
>   `with_ssh'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:130:in`
>   execute_command'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in
>   `block in create_command_and_execute'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in`
>   tap'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in
>   `create_command_and_execute'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:61:in`
>   test'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-passenger-0.2.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/passenger.cap:42:in
>   `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in`
>   instance_exec'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in
>   `run'
>   C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in`
>   block (2 levels) in execute' Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook =>
>   passenger:rvm:hook => passenger:test_which_passenger

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: No not yet. I am thinking its a windows issue wrt ssh keys but not sure